# Finding a function's address in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly, reverse-engineering

I was wondering if anyone knows how to grab the address of the function you are in.  Lets say I hook MessageBoxA().  When MessageBoxA() is called I call me pseudo function called hookMessageboxA().  From within hookMessageBoxA() I want to spit out where MessageBoxA() was called from.  Does that make sense?  Using assembly is probably needed but I am unsure how it could be done.

The below code is wrong, its just something I think might have to be done.  Any help on how to do this in assembly and C++ is greatly appreciated!!!!!

```
DWORD address = 0x00;
_asm {
    mov address, ebp
}
DWORD keyPointerAddr = (DWORD)hInstance + 0x1000 - address + 0x00401000;
char str[255];
    sprintf(str,"That call is coming from [%d]\n", keyPointerAddr);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're interested in (Given you're using Windows), is [StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650%28VS.85%29.aspx). I'd suggest reading the following article for a few hints on using this function:

**[Walking the Callstack](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx)**

Dissecting the code should give you exactly what you're after, albeit in an OS dependant way - the only way. The article should prove handy though, it's not the friendliest looking function :).

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping I wouldnt have to learn more for this :D.

Comment: @user954753 No problem, hopefully the article will save you many hours of grief :).

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need to use any APIs. MSVC provides [an intrinsic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64ez38eh.aspx) to get just the return address:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>

#pragma intrinsic(_ReturnAddress)

__declspec(noinline)
void noinline_func(void)
{
   printf("Return address from %s: %p\n", __FUNCTION__, _ReturnAddress());
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up just bping my hook and tracing back.  The application was hiding ordinals.  I will however use this next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the function you are in, the name of the function is the pointer to it, but I assume you already know that given your current pointer hackery.

Otherwise, you're going to have to walk the current stack. Have a look at [`StackWalk64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and related functions, or the DIA SDK (apparently, I've never looked at it though). Of course, this is MS specific. Other platforms have other methods (as the other person I've just forgotten the username of has said). Otherwise, you could manually walk the stack (if you know the ABI and can access your platform's stack pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in standard C++...  But is possible with knowledge of how the particular compiler happens to compile and run the code, and with diagnostic hooks.  In Mac OS X, for instance, you could use the 'backtrace()' or 'backtrace_symbols()' functions. Consult your platform documentation for more information.

There may be similar routines for other platforms.